# deploy and access azure AS tabular project

Tags: azure, powerbi, ssas-tabular, azure-analysis-services

I've moustly exactly complete steps, described in [this post](https://azure.microsoft.com/ru-ru/blog/first-azure-as/), except that I'm training in northeurope datacenter.

But after succesful deploying model to azure AS I cannot access it with powerBI. It connects to service, but cannot found any models in it.

I suppose it may be some permission problem. 
But while composing model, I can add to project roles only my local user accounts, nor microsoft id's nor azure active directory user.

How it can be done?

Comment: When you created your Azure Analysis Services, what email did you assign as administrator? Did you create any roles in the model in SSDT to grant any email addresses access? When you deployed the model did it succeed an show you that it processed successfully?

Comment: What email did you log into Power BI with? One that is an Azure AS admin or a member of a role in the model?

Comment: thank you for suggestions.
when i created azure AS instance i used azure AD account (because assigning other users (i.e. MS id's) not allowed).
i didnt create any roles (because i cannot add any users except local).
when i deploy model, process succeded.
while connecting from powerBI desktop, it don't ask any credentials.

Comment: Please follow the instructions of this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41783578/5070440

Comment: Thank You, this way works fine. But Josh Caplan somehow (as is seen from his post) connects in "Connect Live" mode.
is there any way to do the same without linking Azure AD - on-prem AD?

Comment: yes. You can connect live. Just make sure that you choose organizational account for the auth the first time you connect. No gateway required. No directory sync from on prem is required though it would be recommended. Azure AD auth is all that's required. Are you having issues with this? Can you describe further?

Comment: unfortunately with "Live" still no luck. there is no models on server PowerBI said.

Comment: what if you try the latest SSMS? Can you see the models? Can you open an MDX query window?

Comment: so you followed the instructions to clear permissions and reconnect with Organizational Account permissions? And you have the latest Power BI Desktop?

Comment: With latest SSMS things a litle bit strange. 
It connects without any errors (or only show this) **regardless** of password I type. 
I can open mdx/dmx query window but there is no any bases/project/models in solution explorer too. Browsing service properties to General tab shows what I dont have enough permissions.
Clearing and switching to org account in latest PowerBI allows me to import tables from my model, but "Live" mode continues show same warning about models absense.
Seems it may be my local machine trouble, so I will try from another environment. 
Thank You for participation.

Comment: Fresh machine works great, so, I think somewhere cached my MS ID, under such I connect to azure first time, and wich I unable to set as admin or add to role in my project.

Comment: You may want to clear the login cache as described here then try again: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/analysis-services/analysis-services-manage#troubleshooting-connection-problems

Comment: Thank You Greg!
Deleting the AADCacheOM folder fixes both SSMS and PowerBI live mode.

Comment: great! I posted that as the answer and hope you will mark it as the answer to help others in the future

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If SSMS is stuck logging in with the wrong user account you may want to [clear the login cache](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/analysis-services/analysis-services-manage?#troubleshooting-connection-problems) then try again.

Comment: Just to mention, deleting the AADCacheOM folder also helps when PowerBI logging wrong user account too.
get ready for next chalenge.